# how does this one assignment change multiple element of my array?

Tags: c++

I was trying to make a Snake game, and I haven't gotten very far before I ran into a problem where one assignment that seems like it should just work, just won't work.

My code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "snake game.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    snakegame gameobj;

    gameobj.displayframe();


    return 0;
}
```

```
#ifndef SNAKE GAME_HPP
#define SNAKE GAME_HPP
#include <iostream>

struct snakenode
{
    snakenode* next;
    int dir;
    char data;
};

class snakegame
{
    public:
        snakegame();
        ~snakegame();
        void updatesg(int direction);
        void displayframe();


    private:
        const static int width = 120;
        const static int height = 30;
        snakenode gamearr[width][height];
        snakenode* head;



};

#endif // SNAKE GAME_HPP
```

```
#include "snake game.hpp"

snakegame::snakegame()
{
 std::cout<< "constructor called \n";
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
         gamearr[i][j].data = '#';
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Head position: (" << width / 2 << ", " << height/2  << ")" << std::endl;

    gamearr[5][5].data = 'O';
    head = &gamearr[5][5];


}

snakegame::~snakegame()
{

}

void snakegame::displayframe()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
         std::cout << gamearr[i][j].data;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I've created a class that holds an array that the constructor initializes to all one character, then I wanted to set the middle element to another character with:

```
gamearr[width/2][height/2].data = 'O';
```

This didn't work (it would randomly work or not for some values of width and heigh ex: 120, 30 didn't but 50, 40 did) so just to test I tried:

```
gamearr[5][5].data = 'O';
```

Somehow this ended up setting multiple elements to O. I've tried to debug it but I can't tell what could possibly be causing this.  This isn't just for 5.

output:

```
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
###############################################################################################O########################
#################################################################O######################################################
###################################O####################################################################################
#####O##################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
```

(hopefully you can see the multiple 'o's that have magically appeared)

I was expecting either the middle element or only one of the elements to be changed.

Comment: Your understanding of arrays is possibly off here because you want a square with 120 columns and 30 rows whereas your array is created with 120 rows and 30 columns.

Comment: You are indexing into the array incorrectly. It is declared in width-height order, but you are looping through it in height-width order, so you are going out of bounds of some of the elements, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: thankyou, this has fixed the issue.

Comment: Then please create an answer according to [answer] as a separate post.

Comment: `snakenode gamearr[width][height];` is the declaration, then you use `i` for height and `j` for width and access `gamearr[i][j].data`. Use meaningful variable names. Already `h` instead of `i` and `w` instead of `j` would have helped. Or even better `max_height` and `max_width` for the size and `height` and `width` for the indices. Or make up your mind for better names. Spending time on choosing good names will eliminate many bugs early